# Multiple targets and library from bridging header issue

Tags: xcode, swift

I've added Today extension to my Swift project, because of that I had to add it to targets for my Model class, which resulted in "Use of unresolved identifier..." when using libraries imported in ObjC bridging header. There's no issue for libraries written in Swift(imported directly in class). How can I solve this?

[image: multiple targets]

[image]